# Is the closure of a set contained in the convex hull?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$. Do we have $\bar A\subseteq \text{conv}(A)$?Counterexample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  If $A$ is open and convex, then $\textbf{conv}(A) = A$.

For a specific example, suppose $A$ is the open unit ball.
Then $\textbf{conv}(A) = A \nsupseteq \bar{A}$.